# CURL to Python Requests API CALL

Tags: python, curl, python-requests

I am trying to convert a CURL command to python code using requests using a tool.

This is the [tool](https://curl.trillworks.com/).

**CURL COMMAND**:

```
curl -X POST -H 'content-type: multipart/form-data' -F 'file=@"image-api.jpg";filename="image_app.png"' -H "Authorization: Bearer eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwczpcL1wvYWNjb3VudHMuc25hcGNoYXQuY29tXC9hY2NvdW50c1wvb2F1dGgyXC90b2tlbiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCIsImVuYyI6IkExMjhDQkMtSFMyNTYiLCJhbGciOiJkaXIiLCJraWQiOiJhY2Nlc3MtdG9rZW4tYTEyOGNiYy1oczI1Ni4wIn0..s2rMbO22nSfSqhuBwq68QA.Gu0MBlHpBXEdIS89YQSFrgS6nwtZT3NCax004UcjcFzOT_-ioXwoh8mwEethNTmVfY-F21CZ8ceTeAZQbhYiFqN5cWrnk2WX_KIw8Uq-D1jbrwrhqbFshzUMXqCAoJIe9DLzZYXmYdia1l9mMMdiSyyep9dFGzwOgB_FdGDU-fUIuEGEZyXdeyCM_4TDf652JPOHc_ldZmHivpmfa9QacMXjJxrVN0Y10m0_FC6p_q7WPdyVtUYSk1EMmHjIPNUSvRTSjNPLHhfH_WXNWcVPjy07p3bwNYc2uj4Woy-VYci51M4vuWRZrAMs6GO4eQeAu4Z7rKIc_Zhu4CBZcU1yqg4joQFnWUXRi_a_fq1SeeQYrFC_NFX5jgsz7ElCvPd2s0s0rs6FdBTNDPDdM-o2W35a8Ew46KRHrOT2FN6yJyVVI_hrz0hBajsC-BU4u2i90KlV0SKQOOR19t5RuGLJbLXxRdVL_s172CdQwHUejhjuusq_r0JmxtwCVBCEzMcOzdJ-2u7PPEZbsAiVpdS9MJdDQyVQOJ_e0UlIN6qNKhFSKS9-88mFvDS4MmFdenfacBbGJycjgNx_TgIjnpbk2KAYe2-_mKbMkOctxUA-3ZAfpjMF0UUO46csIJEpmmwmUOp5qt4jz2EbSZjvjmyPIxXF38Qv3g-HGBPUQF8vvx0BHd-WkB6Hs86jjXBlplUD8AgIo-YNoIeH4-2umCw6b-DuGFuG3ZTcyzM8P1lrPCg.SOqmXSkT1dNBh4QknnuBXQ" https://adsapi.snapchat.com/v1/media/577e68af-0b9b-4ae6-8bbb-22ac6910557f/upload
```

**Python Code**:

```
import requests

headers = {
    'content-type': 'multipart/form-data',
    'Authorization': 'Bearer eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwczpcL1wvYWNjb3VudHMuc25hcGNoYXQuY29tXC9hY2NvdW50c1wvb2F1dGgyXC90b2tlbiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCIsImVuYyI6IkExMjhDQkMtSFMyNTYiLCJhbGciOiJkaXIiLCJraWQiOiJhY2Nlc3MtdG9rZW4tYTEyOGNiYy1oczI1Ni4wIn0..s2rMbO22nSfSqhuBwq68QA.Gu0MBlHpBXEdIS89YQSFrgS6nwtZT3NCax004UcjcFzOT_-ioXwoh8mwEethNTmVfY-F21CZ8ceTeAZQbhYiFqN5cWrnk2WX_KIw8Uq-D1jbrwrhqbFshzUMXqCAoJIe9DLzZYXmYdia1l9mMMdiSyyep9dFGzwOgB_FdGDU-fUIuEGEZyXdeyCM_4TDf652JPOHc_ldZmHivpmfa9QacMXjJxrVN0Y10m0_FC6p_q7WPdyVtUYSk1EMmHjIPNUSvRTSjNPLHhfH_WXNWcVPjy07p3bwNYc2uj4Woy-VYci51M4vuWRZrAMs6GO4eQeAu4Z7rKIc_Zhu4CBZcU1yqg4joQFnWUXRi_a_fq1SeeQYrFC_NFX5jgsz7ElCvPd2s0s0rs6FdBTNDPDdM-o2W35a8Ew46KRHrOT2FN6yJyVVI_hrz0hBajsC-BU4u2i90KlV0SKQOOR19t5RuGLJbLXxRdVL_s172CdQwHUejhjuusq_r0JmxtwCVBCEzMcOzdJ-2u7PPEZbsAiVpdS9MJdDQyVQOJ_e0UlIN6qNKhFSKS9-88mFvDS4MmFdenfacBbGJycjgNx_TgIjnpbk2KAYe2-_mKbMkOctxUA-3ZAfpjMF0UUO46csIJEpmmwmUOp5qt4jz2EbSZjvjmyPIxXF38Qv3g-HGBPUQF8vvx0BHd-WkB6Hs86jjXBlplUD8AgIo-YNoIeH4-2umCw6b-DuGFuG3ZTcyzM8P1lrPCg.SOqmXSkT1dNBh4QknnuBXQ',
}

files = {
    'file': ('"image-api.jpg";filename', open('"image-api.jpg";filename', 'rb')),
}

response = requests.post('https://adsapi.snapchat.com/v1/media/577e68af-0b9b-4ae6-8bbb-22ac6910557f/upload', headers=headers, files=files)
```

but , when I try to run the python code using python test.py (where test.py has this above code)

I get the following error:

```
$ python test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 9, in <module>
    'file': ('"image-api.jpg";filename', open('"image-api.jpg";filename', 'rb')),
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: '"image-api.jpg";filename'
```

I don't know, what I am doing wrong here. I would certainly appreciate it if anybody helps with this one.

BTW, I am referring to documentation from this [link](https://marketingapi.snapchat.com/docs/#upload-media-video). (Upload Media - Image Section)

Comment: use `"image-api.jpg"` without `;filename` - and with `" "` or `' '` but not with both `' " " '`

Comment: don't put real `Authorization` in question because someone may use it to send image instead of you - and you may have problems.

Answer (score 1):

Page is not ideal and sometimes it has problem to correctly convert some options.

I can't test it but normally you should use only `'image-api.jpg'` without `;filename`.

And use `' '` or `" "` but not both.

```
files = {
    'file': ('image-api.jpg', open('image-api.jpg', 'rb')),
}
```

Eventually you may need `/full/path/to/image-api.jpg` in `open()`

---

**BTW:**

You can send `curl` and `requests` to page https://httpbin.org/post and it will send back all information from you and then you can compare if `curl` and `requests` send the same data.

---

**EDIT:**

Testing with page `httpbin.org` I found that you have to remove header `'content-type'`. Option `files=...` will add this automatically and this send files. If I add this header manually then it doesn't send files